# Add List to List in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

I am facing an issue that i cannot solve on my own right now.
Its about the following snippet:

```
counter = 0
appendList = []
valueList = [[0], [0]]

for i in range(0,3):

    valueList[1] = counter
    print "Loop " , i  , " valueList: " , valueList
    print "Appending (valueList): " , valueList , " to (appendList): " , appendList
    appendList.append(valueList)
    counter = counter + 1


print "Final appendList: " , appendList
```

This results in the following output:

```
Loop  0  valueList:  [[0], 0]
Appending (valueList):  [[0], 0]  to (appendList):  []
Loop  1  valueList:  [[0], 1]
Appending (valueList):  [[0], 1]  to (appendList):  [[[0], 1]]
Loop  2  valueList:  [[0], 2]
Appending (valueList):  [[0], 2]  to (appendList):  [[[0], 2], [[0], 2]]
Final appendList:  [[[0], 2], [[0], 2], [[0], 2]]
```

I wanted the Snippet to add different `List-Items` to the `appendList`. The final result should have looked like this:

```
[[[0], 0], [[0], 1], [[0], 2]]
```

But as you can see, the snippet fills the `appendList` with the same values of the highest counter.

Can someone please explain this behavior to me or tell me, where my mistake is?

Comment: Assign a copy every time, like this `appendList.append(valueList[:])`

Comment: Thanks mate, that solved my issue. Can you explain why?

Comment: Writing an answer on that right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valueList` is the same object each time you append it, so modifying it in one place appears to modify it everywhere.

```
>>> a = [0]
>>> b = a
>>> a[0] = 42
>>> b
[42]
```

You need to append a copy of it in order to add a new list each time.

```
appendList.append(valueList[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
counter = 0
appendList = []
valueList = [[0], [0]]

for i in range(0,3):

    valueList[1] = counter
    print "Loop " , i  , " valueList: " , valueList
    print "Appending (valueList): " , valueList , " to (appendList): " , appendList
    appendList.append(valueList[:])
    counter = counter + 1


print "Final appendList: " , appendList
```

Output:

```
Loop  0  valueList:  [[0], 0]
Appending (valueList):  [[0], 0]  to (appendList):  []
Loop  1  valueList:  [[0], 1]
Appending (valueList):  [[0], 1]  to (appendList):  [[[0], 0]]
Loop  2  valueList:  [[0], 2]
Appending (valueList):  [[0], 2]  to (appendList):  [[[0], 0], [[0], 1]]
Final appendList:  [[[0], 0], [[0], 1], [[0], 2]]
```

**Explanation:**

When you assign `valuelist` object, all elements are assign from referance object. So, instead `b = a`, you can do `b = a [:]` because it's only copy each time from this object.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a[:] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[4, 5, 6]
>>> b = a [:]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Although it solves the problem, this doesn't explain why and is an exact copy of @thefourtheye's comment.

Comment: Okk just wait. I am writing explanation

Comment: @ppperry: Now it's okk?

Answer (score 0):

`appendList` contains a **reference** to the current value of `valueList`, so when you modify `valueList`, the copies in `appendList` change. You need to create a **copy** of `valueList` each time you put in it `appendList`.

Answer (score 0):

valueList still points to a single object. You can check this by printing out the `id(valueList)`. [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) gives **identity** of the object. i.e. the memory address of the object. In your example, if you print the id, it will be always same.

```
counter = 0
appendList = []
valueList = [[0], [0]]

for i in range(0,3):
    print "id of valueList before", id(valueList)
    #creates a copy of valueList.
    valueList = valueList[:]
    print "id of valueList after", id(valueList)
    valueList[1] = counter
    print "Loop " , i  , " valueList: " , valueList
    print "Appending (valueList): " , valueList , " to (appendList): ", appendList
    appendList.append(valueList)
    counter = counter + 1


print "Final appendList: " , appendList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
appendList = []
valueList = [[0], [0]]

print(valueList[1][0])

for i in range(0,3):

    print(counter)
    valueList[1][0] = counter # this was wrong
    print ("Loop " , i  , " valueList: " , valueList)
    print ("Appending (valueList): " , valueList , " to (appendList): " , appendList)
    appendList.append(valueList)
    valueList = [[0], [0]] # and this was absent
    counter += 1

print(appendList)

[[[0], [0]], [[0], [1]], [[0], [2]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good habit is also to check the efficiency of your code afterwards: you are defining multiple variables while (to me) you are interested in appendList.

`appendList = [ [[0], x] for x in range(3) ] # doStuff for index in range of n`
`print appendList`
With list comprehension you can reduce it to only the necessary computation.